# How To Use Bootstrap Nested Column Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to achieve bootstrap nested column div but this is not responsive I want to achieve the fully responsive grid system In BootStrap

this is what i want to achieve in bootstrap grid system[image: BootStrap Grid System]

This is my html markup

```
<div class="col-md-12 topSpace">
   <div class="col-md-3 text-center"></div>
   <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="md-col-6 col-centered"></div>
```

this is the css markup

```
.col-centered{
margin:0 auto;
}

.topSpace{
top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This below html markup should work.

```
<div class="col-md-12">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      1
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-6">
      2
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      4
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/SJ3EYuxOQM

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to @John's answer is

```
<div class="col-md-12">

  <div class="col-md-3">
     1
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="row">       
      <div class="col-md-12">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        4
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>  
  <div class="col-md-3">
    3
  </div>

</div>
```

It differs how the items are listed for smaller screen width:

- For my answer: 1,2,4,3
- For @john's answer: 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1):

This one also work try It,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            DIV1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            DIV2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            DIV3
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            DIV4
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```